# Intercom Rest API search contact (with PHP)

Tags: php, rest, intercom

I'm trying to retrieve a contact in Intercom through their REST API. I'm using the following code but I get the following error :

CODE

```
        try {

            $postdataarray['query'] = [ "field" => "email","operator" => "=","value" => $value['email']];
            $postData = json_encode($postdataarray);
            $postHeader = [
                'Authorization:Bearer ergergergergergergergerg',
                'Accept: application/json',
                'Content-Type: application/json -d'
            ];
            $curl = curl_init("https://api.intercom.io/contacts/search/");
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $postHeader);
            $content = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            echo $content;

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            error_log($e->getMessage());
            
        }
```

ERROR

{ "errors": [ { "code": "not_found", "message": "The requested resource does not exist; check your path and try again" } ], "type": "error.list" }

UPDATE
Now my code looks like this :

```
    try {

        $postdataarray['query'] = [ "field" => "email","operator" => "=","value" => $value['email']];
        $postData = json_encode($postdataarray);
        $postHeader = [
            'Authorization:Bearer zefzefzefzefzef',
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Intercom-Version: 2.3',
            'Content-Type: application/json -d'
        ];
        $curl = curl_init("https://api.intercom.io/contacts/search");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $postHeader);
        $content = curl_exec($curl);
        var_dump ($content);
        curl_close($curl);
      

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        error_log($e->getMessage());

    }
```

Still doesn't work

Comment: Can you try to change `https://api.intercom.io/contacts/search/` to `https://api.intercom.io/contacts/search` ?

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: check which api version you are using, https://developers.intercom.com/building-apps/docs/update-your-api-version and try adding to your headers `Intercom-Version: 2.3`

Comment: That works! but it gives me 1 as a result ...

Comment: That's because you have set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE` and as a result the curl_exec only returns true or false

Comment: When I set it to true, it outputs nothing :(

Comment: try to var_dump instead of echo

Comment: string '' (length=0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229242/discussion-between-justberare-and-dimitris-filippou).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are sending a post request to retrieve a contact you should be using get method

change this line:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
```

to

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the problem was the token of the intercom did not have permission to access the resource. So, please check your token and the issue should be resolved.